# fields_for doesn't render loop through fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.0.1, and I really don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I have a model `ChallengeList` and a model `Challenge`. `ChallengeList` has many `Challenges`:

```
#ChallengeList
has_many :challenges, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenges
```

I want to make a nested form that allows the user to update challenges while editing a list (code in HAML, but should make sense):

```
= form_for @challenge_list do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :title, "Title (optional)"
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title
  -# etc, fields for challenge list

  ="#{@challenge_list.challenges.length} challenges"
  -f.fields_for :challenges do |builder|
    .field
      = builder.text_field :description
      %br/
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

But when I try out my form, the field_for section doesn't show anything, even if `@challenge_list` contains more than 1 challenge. (e.g. `challenge_list.challenges.length` turns up a number >0).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot an equals sign for `fields_for`:

```
  = "#{@challenge_list.challenges.length} challenges"
  = f.fields_for :challenges do |builder|
    .field
      = builder.text_field :description
      %br/
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```